# Angular 6 - Display data from database with *ngFor

Tags: database, angular, angular6

I'm trying to display datas from a database. I've found examples on the internet but it's not working at all

Error from Eclipse:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading

**My html file:**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let questionnaire of questionnaires | async">{{questionnaire.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**My typeScript file:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {QuestionnaireService} from '../services/questionnaire.service';
@Injectable()


@Component({
  selector: 'app-qcm',
  templateUrl: './qcm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./qcm.component.sass']
})
export class QcmComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  questionnaires :any = [];
  constructor(private questionnaireService: QuestionnaireService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.questionnaires = this.questionnaireService.getQuestionnaire(1);
  }

}
```

**My service:**

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class QuestionnaireService {

  user: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getQuestionnaire(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}getQuestionnaire`);
  }
}
```

**Here is my webservice methode (spring hibernate)**

```
@GET
    @Path("/getQuestionnaire")
    public Questionnaire getQuestionnaire(@QueryParam("id") Long id) throws Exception {
        return FacadeBackOffice.getInstance().getQuestionnaireService().getQuestionnaire(id);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sorry, I'm gonna try to be more explicit...

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error ?

Comment: @MotFranc  Can u check any error on your developer.console?

Comment: I have this error in Eclipse : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading. So i've changed my code to put an id. but I still end up with the same error

Comment: @MotFranc you mean inside service??

Comment: Yes inside my spring hibernate back end

Comment: @MotFranc it;s nothing to do with Angular. You have to the fix the service itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TODO list:**

1. Check if the api call goes to the right URL.

   Howto: Check the request and response on network tab.
2. `questionnaires` in your component is an `Observable` and not an array.

   Why: `HttpClient` `get` returns an Observable, so you have two choices:

   1. use the async pipe (you are doing it the right way)
   2. `subscribe` to the `observable` to send the request and in the anonymous function passed to the subscribe assign `questionnaires` class variable with the response (or subset).

**Improvement:**

Makes no sense to populate `questionnaires` class variable two ways (Input of the component and result of a http get request). Leave only one option here.

Answer (score 0):

you might be facing asynch data call issue.
Please try subscribing to your service and then storing the data to your array. e.g.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.questionnaireService.getQuestionnaire()
.subscribe(
    (data) => {
    this.questionnaires= data;
    });
      }
```

Comment: OP already have specified async in html. So it will subscribe internally by angular

Comment: I completely missed that but usually i won't prefer asynch in HTML!

Comment: me too use the same pattern. But OP makes confuse , that's why I pointed

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the `async` out of the html, and then putting a `.subscribe()` on the the service instead. Also, remove the `@Input()`, it looks like it is unneeded since your component's `ngOnInit` will be populating the array.

I added a `console.log()` so you know what is in your service call in case you might need something like `this.questionarries = response.body`.

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let questionnaire of questionnaires">{{questionnaire.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**component**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {QuestionnaireService} from '../services/questionnaire.service';
@Injectable()


@Component({
  selector: 'app-qcm',
  templateUrl: './qcm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./qcm.component.sass']
})
export class QcmComponent implements OnInit {
  questionnaires :any = [];
  constructor(private questionnaireService: QuestionnaireService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.questionnaireService.getQuestionnaire().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.questionnaires = response;
        console.log(this.questionnaries);
      }
    );
  }
}
```